Unexpected null value for user in flutter project
I want to have an account creation process in my Flutter project so that new users who have just registered can fill out the user variables in a clean way on different pages, instead of just going straight to the Home page. I am trying to modify a Mitch Koko project where he just has the user edit the variables once they're in the app itself (the Twitter clone app tutorial). I copied the way he gets the user profile that he uses to access the bio variable. However, the user is still null when I use it in the build widget to access the name variable. My idea is to check the name variable to see if it is 'default' which I hardcoded for every new user.
enter image description here
Here is the problematic code itself... Again, user seems to be null. The user id variable is correct though.
I have been debugging and tried access user id in different ways. I can't think of anything else to try.

On Stack Overflow, please don't show pictures of text and code. Copy the text into the question itself and format it so that it's easy to read, copy, and search. You can edit the question to correct this using the edit link at the bottom.

loadUser() will take time but you declare user as not null.
Replace (user!.name == 'default') by (user?.name == 'default') or use other method like future builder etc.
class RegisterOrHomeState extends State<RegisterOrHome> {
  final auth  = AuthService();
  late final databaseProvider = Provider.of<DatabaseProvider>(context, listen: false);

  // user info
  UserProfile? user;
  String currentUserId = AuthService().getCurrentUid();
  // on startup
  @override
  void initState() {

    super.initState();
    // load user info
    loadUser(); 

  }

  Future<void> loadUser() async {
    // get the user profile info
  user = await databaseProvider.userProfile(currentUserId);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    // Error is here
    // --> loadUser() will take time but you declare user as not null
    // replace (user!.name == 'default') by (user?.name == 'default') or use other method
    // like future builder etc.
    if (user!.name == 'default'){
    return const Create AccountPageOne();
    }else{
    return const HomePage();
    }
  }
}


i would also add a few print statements here and there just to check things

Hmm, well now it's getting an error, No batch result object ID... It seems my DatabaseProvider object is the source, which is critical to loading the user. So it's still null. Something is not working right with that.

String currentUserId = AuthService().getCurrentUid();
put this thing in loadUser() with await if getCurrentUid returns future.

So the if statement is now (user?.name == 'default'), and the String currentUserId = AuthService().getCurrentUid() is at the top of the body of the loadUser method. I'm now back to the same original problem though. The user is still null, and it's just taking me to the home screen... I appreciate all the suggestions though! Hopefully I'm getting closer to the real problem.
